# weird syntax errors on executing commands in mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, command-line, terminal, visual-studio-code

every time I try to execute some command such as 'pyenv versions' or open vs code by executing the command 'code .', both of these commands result in the same weird error:

```
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Syntax Warning: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Why are these commands interpreted as pdf files at all ? here is the screenshot of one of such command runs:

[image: Here is the screenshot of one of such runs:]

Also, when I remove the following from .bash_profile, the 'pdftotext version 3.04' and the other lines disappear from the terminal :

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

So after removing the above lines from .bash_profile, the terminal looks like this:

[image: new terminal]

Also, when I run the command 'set -x; code . ', I get the following:

```
Last login: Wed Jul 31 15:10:24 on ttys001
martand ~ $ set -x; code . 
+ code .
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Syntax Warning: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local url_path=
++ local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
++ (( i = 0 ))
++ (( i < 14 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 14 ))
++ ch=U
++ [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=U
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 14 ))
....
++ return 1
```

Comment: seems like an aliasing problem, or something defined in `.bashrc` or the like. Can you provide more info, such as what do you get when running `which code` for example ? Do usual commands work (e.g. `ls`, `grep` ...) ?

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your terminal, or an exact copy and paste of the entire line where you enter the command (including `$` or whatever your prompt looks like exactly).

Comment: Another useful information to add: the full output when setting trace mode on: e.g. `set -x; code .`

Comment: @deceze : added the screenshot. please check, Thanks! :)

Comment: So for some reasons everything is invoking `pdftotext` on your shell…

Comment: @Derlin : which code outputs: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code. Also..ls, grep works.

Comment: @Derlin : I added the output for ' set -x; code . ' . Check the updated question. Thanks! :)